# vscode jupyter strange autocomplete "%%!"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, autocomplete, jupyter

[in jupyter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRGTp.png)

I recently updated it, and there is a problem when Jupyter performs automatic completion.

[in editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KznPY.png)

As shown in the picture above, there is no problem unless it is Jupyter.

Why does this %%! occur?

Downgrade does not change to normal now.

os: EndeavourOS Linux x86_64 5.13.13-arch1-1

vscode version: 1.60.0

jupyter extension version: 2021.8.2041215044

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've got the same issue. Very annoying. Also happens when you try to make a docstring. ''' becomes '''%%!'''

Comment: Reported bug to vscode github repo: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/7880

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because the "enter" is being used to accept the suggestions instead of "tab". You can fix this following these steps:

- Click in "File" > "Preferences" > "Ctrl[+,]".
- Fill the search bar with this text "Accept Suggestion on Enter".
- The actual value set in checkbox could be "on" or "smart", switch to "off".

This must resolve your problem.

Comment: This didn't work for me in the latest version. As per https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/7880#issuecomment-958594302, rolling back to v2021.8.1236758218 removes the problem until it gets fixed.

Answer (score -1):

It's jupyter notebook related, such as `# %%` to create a new cell.

Comment: So, that sort of explains why the bug happens... But why would anyone want this? Auto-complete for pretty much every line of code is %%! "It's a feature, not a bug"?